# Como fazer um texto ficar de uma cor, e voltar à original?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando fazer, um "sistema" *online*, *offline*
Quando o usuário clica em "• *Online*", na qual a bolinha é verde, ela fica vermelha, e o texto atualiza para "• *Offline*"

Procurei, tentei, não achei e não conseguir fazer...
O que eu fiz foi isso:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success" id="foo"></i> Online</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var online = 0;

      function myFunction()
        {
            online = 1;
            document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "darkred";

            if (online = 1) {
              document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "darkred";
            } else {
              document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "darkgreen";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer assim se quiser:

```js
var icone = document.querySelector(".fa");
var texto = document.getElementById("foo");

icone.style.color = "green";  // inicializa com o botão verde
texto.textContent = " Online"; // inicializa com o texto online

function myFunction() {  
  
  if(icone.style.color == "green"){
    icone.style.color = "red";
    texto.textContent = " Offline";
  } else {
    icone.style.color = "green";
    texto.textContent = " Online";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success" id="foo"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sua função possui um erro no `if`: o operador de comparação seriam dois sinais `==` e não apenas um (`=`). No JavaScript você compara se um valor é igual a outro com dois `==` — em alguns casos, até três: `===` (**[veja aqui os operadores usados em vários casos](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)**).

Outro problema é que dentro da função você está redefinindo o valor de `online` para `1`, isso significa que ele sempre vai ser `1` no `if` seguinte.

Mesmo assim, também é preciso alterar o valor da variável `online` quando uma das condições for atendida (`if...else`). Em nenhum momento isso é feito, logo o valor da variável é sempre o mesmo.

Minha sugestão que que você defina no CSS a cor inicial do link, bem como o espaçamento do círculo ao texto, usando um `margin-right`, assim você não precisa colocar um caractere de espaço entre o círculo e o texto.

Para alterar o texto, pode usar os métodos `nextSibling.textContent`. O `nextSibling` irá selecionar o próximo nó após o círculo (no caso, o texto). E o `textContent` irá alterar o texto.

Para alterar a cor do link (logo, do círculo e do texto juntos), pode usar o método `.parentNode`. Como na função o seletor usado é o círculo, o `.parentNode` irá selecionar a tag `<a>` que é o pai.

Com essas correções, seu código poderia ser desta forma:

```js
var online = 1;

function myFunction(){
   var onOff = document.getElementById("foo");

   if(online == 1){
      online = 0;
      onOff.parentNode.style.color = "darkred";
      onOff.nextSibling.textContent = "Offline";
   }else{
      online = 1;
      onOff.parentNode.style.color = "darkgreen";
      onOff.nextSibling.textContent = "Online";
   }
}
```

```css
/* seleciona a tag <a> onde o atributo onclick começa com myFunction*/
a[onclick^='myFunction']{
   color: darkgreen;
}

#foo{
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">
   <i class="fa fa-circle text-success" id="foo"></i>Online
</a>
```

Comment: O AP nada disse a respeito de mudar a cor do texto. To com dedo em cima do down  :)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando de short-if:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success MINHA_CLASSE_VERDE" id="foo"></i>Online</a>

<script>
  var online = true;

  function myFunction(e) {
    online = !online;
    e.innerHTML = online ? '<i class="fa fa-circle text-success MINHA_CLASSE_VERDE" id="foo"></i> Online' : '<i class="fa fa-circle text-success MINHA_CLASSE_VERMELHA" id="foo"></i> Offilne';
  }
</script>
```

---

**Demonstração:**
https://jsfiddle.net/leonardomsnt/mvc082n5/

---

**Aplicação**

1. Copie e cole o código
2. Crie duas classes, MINHA_CLASSE_VERDE e MINHA_CLASSE_VERMELHA

   ```
   .MINHA_CLASSE_VERDE { background: darkgreen}
   .MINHA_CLASSE_VERMELHA { background: darkred}
   ```

---

**Recomendo:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator